# Issues connecting to wso2 esb management console's features/services - esb version 4.5.1

Tags: wso2, esb

I am experiencing an issue accessing the wso2 esb management console: version 4.5.1

When I log into the console I get a large stack trace and cannot access any of the features/services running on the esb.

Can anybody help?

Stack trace below:

```
error
The following error details are available. Please refer logs for more details.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Cannot get all services. Backend service may be unavailable
at org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.ui.ServiceAdminClient.handleException(ServiceAdminClient.java:427)
at org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.ui.ServiceAdminClient.getAllServices(ServiceAdminClient.java:89)
at org.apache.jsp.service_002dmgt.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:168)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:161)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:599)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:536)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:265)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:966)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:643)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:637)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttribute_7(template_jsp.java:539)
at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:290)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:161)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:477)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:258)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:172)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Cannot retrieve security scenario for service CampusITCourseUpdateService
at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.stub.ServiceAdminStub.listServices(ServiceAdminStub.java:8211)
at org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.ui.ServiceAdminClient.getAllServices(ServiceAdminClient.java:87)
... 98 more
```

"

Answer (score 2):

This can be due to the corrupted service meta files.
You can tryout the following steps.

1. Shut-down the server
2. Take a backup of the following directory. 
   /repository/deployment/server/servicemetafiles
3. Delete the content of the above directory.
4. Start the server.

Answer (score 0):

First check, you have any data base connections,will that data
base is shutdown.

If it ok then, again go to the www.wso2.org then download the new zip
 file, and shift all services to that server. Check with data base
 woking or not, then start the server.

Hope this will help you,any doubts let me know..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem happends when you are using the H2 database and the wso2 proccess is killed abruptly.

In my case i was debugging an .arr service (RemoteProvisioningServiceWS.aar) with eclipse and wso2 started in debug mode, the eclipse frozes sunddenly and i had to kill eclipse and wso2. When i tried to restart wso2 the .arr that i was debugging apparently did not load properly.

```
[2015-01-26 16:18:51,470] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration} -  Error occured while notifying observer
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot handle service DEPLOY event for service: RemoteProvisioningServiceWS
        at org.wso2.carbon.security.deployment.SecurityDeploymentInterceptor.serviceUpdate(SecurityDeploymentInterceptor.java:205)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.notifyObservers(AxisConfiguration.java:651)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.addServiceGroup(AxisConfiguration.java:405)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.addServiceGroup(DeploymentEngine.java:606)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:100)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:810)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:59)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:70)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.persistence.PersistenceUtils.getResourceDocumentElement(PersistenceUtils.java:405)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.persistence.file.ServiceGroupFilePersistenceManager.beginTransaction(ServiceGroupFilePersistenceManager.java
:78)
        at org.wso2.carbon.security.deployment.SecurityDeploymentInterceptor.serviceUpdate(SecurityDeploymentInterceptor.java:165)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:677)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2116)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2022)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1114)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 29 more
[2015-01-26 16:18:51,579]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  Deploying Web service: RemoteProvisioningServiceWS.aar - f
ile:/C:/WSO2AS~1.0B/bin/../repository/deployment/server/axis2services/RemoteProvisioningServiceWS.aar
```

And if you try to open the list of services un the wso2 web console, and error appears:

```
System Error Occurred
error
The following error details are available. Please refer logs for more details.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Cannot get all services. Backend service may be unavailable
at org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.ui.ServiceAdminClient.handleException(ServiceAdminClient.java:427)
at org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.ui.ServiceAdminClient.getAllServices(ServiceAdminClient.java:89)
at org.apache.jsp.service_002dmgt.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:168)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
```

It seems that is a problem with the database, I dont recommend to use h2 db and configure wso2 in a mySql for a development and production environtments, only use h2 in local.

To solve the problem: Download the same version of wso2 unzip and copy or install all your services and aplication again, restart and everything will be ok again.